# Parse a JSX file to extract the attributes of the Import statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, jsx

There is a jsx file with contents

```
<import name="abcd" color="green" age="25" />
<View color={dsdssd}>
    <IBG
        color={[color.imagecolor, color.image125]}
        imageStyle={[styles.imageStyle, styles.image125]}
        source={{ uri: contents.aimeecard }} >
        <View color={styles.titleContainer}>
            <Text color={[{green: 45}, styles.mainTileText]}</Text>
            <View color={[abcde.text]} />
        </View>
</View>
```

I need to fetch the details of first line using python script:
Expected output
name="abcd"
color="green"
age="25"

Also the path of jsx file is passed through list
ex: [abcd/file1.jsx , dcef/file2.jsx]

Python code tried for fetching jsx file through the list

```
for file in jsx_path:
   data = md.parse("file")
   print( file.firstChild.tagName )
```

Values are not fetched and getting error.

Can anyone help me in resolving this?

Comment: What parser are you using, seems like the md.parse("file") is taking the string literal "file" in as an argument, rather than an actual file object.  The following line would then need to read something along the lines of `print( data.firstChild.tagName )` since you're storing the parsed data in var `data`, not var `file`.

Comment: @TylerStoney even after change, its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `jsx_path` is the list containing all the paths to the jsx files, you can iterate over each and use a context manager to avoid closing explicitly the files like so:

```py
data = ""

for file in jsx_path:
    with open(file) as f:
        data += f.readline()[8:-4] + "\n"

print(data)  # name="abcd" color="green" age="25"
```

Following your comment, if you want to output it as a dict, you can tweak the previous code:

```py
import re

data = []

for file in jsx_path:
    with open(file) as f:
        data.append(re.split('\W+|=', f.readline()[8:-4]))

data_dict = []

for d in data:
   data_dict.append({key:value for (key, value) in zip(d[::2], d[1::2])})

print(data_dict)  # {'name': 'abcd', 'color': 'green', 'age': '25'}
```

Note that this is a hack. I only read the JSX file sequentially because your use case is simple enough to do so. You can also use a dedicated parser by extending the stlib class `HTMLParser`:

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class JSXImportParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "import":
            self._import_attrs = {key:value for (key, value) in attrs}

    @property
    def import_attrs(self):
        return self._import_attrs


parser = JSXImportParser()
data = []

for file in jsx_path:
    with open(file) as f:
        parser.feed(f.read())
        data.append(parser.import_attrs)
        print(data)  # [{'name': 'abcd', 'color': 'green', 'age': '25'}]
```

Note that this only extracts the details of the last import tag in each file, you can alter this behavior by tweaking the `_import_attrs` class attribute.

Edit: Following your additional comment about the requirement to use an XML parser library, the same thing can be achieved using `ElementTree` by sampling the file to extract only what's interesting for you (the import tag):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = []

for file in jsx_path:
    with open(file) as f:
        import_statement = ET.XML(f.readline())
        data.append(import_statement.attrib)

print(data)  # [{'name': 'abcd', 'color': 'green', 'age': '25'}]
```

Of course this only works if the import statement is on the first line, if it's not the case, you'll have to locate it first before calling `ET.XML`.

Comment: but expected output is "name" variable should have the value as "abcd" likewise go for other variable color and age also. I should be able to fetch details/values for variables

Comment: "name="sbcd" color="green" age="27" "This is the output. How can i convert the str to dict? name key should have the value @rmpr

Comment: Updated answer with what you asked for

Comment: is there any way to read jsx file using xml reader? Just need to fetch import tag ,irrespective of line nos @RMPR

Comment: Reading a JSX file using a XML reader is not possible using the default parser because it's not a valid XML file, you can tweak the HTMLParser in Python standard library to achieve something similar like shown in the answer, don't forget to give an upvote if it helped and mark the answer as valid.

Comment: provided solution worked, but I want to use xml reader to read jsx file due to some constraints.Even JSX file as root=view, then why its not possible to read the import tag?using elementree or xml reader- @RMPR

Comment: LIke I said, a JSX is not a valid XML file in the sense of correctness, have a look at [syntactical correctness and error-handling of XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Syntactical_correctness_and_error-handling), "A single root element contains all the other elements" is the rule broken here, and that's why ET throws an exception, nevertheless, if you absolutely want to use ET or xml reader, you'll have to extract the `import` line from the file, and apply a XML parser to it, as shown on the last edit