# How to parse an irregular XML file which has multiple lines

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have an XML file named as file.txt as shown below:

```
<message><header><msg-date></msg-date><msg-time></msg-time><sys-id></sys-id></header><record><remittance-details></remittance-details><source-sys-id></source-sys-id></message>
<message><header><msg-date></msg-date><msg-time></msg-time><sys-id></sys-id></header><record><remittance-details></remittance-details><source-sys-id></source-sys-id></message>
<message><header><msg-date></msg-date><msg-time></msg-time><sys-id></sys-id></header><record><remittance-details></remittance-details><source-sys-id></source-sys-id></message>
<message><header><msg-date></msg-date><msg-time></msg-time><sys-id></sys-id></header><record><remittance-details></remittance-details><source-sys-id></source-sys-id></message>
<message><header><msg-date></msg-date><msg-time></msg-time><sys-id></sys-id></header><record><remittance-details></remittance-details><source-sys-id></source-sys-id></message>
```

I need to process the above file after parsing it to a standard format like below in the file:

```
<message>
  <header>
    <msg-date></msg-date>
    <msg-time></msg-time>
    <sys-id></sys-id>
  </header>
  <record>
    <remittance-details></remittance-details>
  </record>
</message>
```

updated the xml details to avoid confusion.
The examples shown above are just for understanding as unable to share the whole details here(pls ignore if there any tag missing).

I have written the below code to parse it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree as etree
import os
import sys
File_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(File_path)
file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'file.txt')
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
dom = etree.parse(file,parser=parser )
xmlstr = etree.tostring(dom, pretty_print=True)
with open (file, "wb") as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)
```

However, its parsing the first line of the file and not parsing the complete file, so the processing is getting failed. Therefore, would like to understand how to parse the complete xml lines in the file to process it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse a JSX file to extract the attributes of the Import statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249299/parse-a-jsx-file-to-extract-the-attributes-of-the-import-statement)

Comment: Even if a root element is added, the input is still not XML.There are no end tags for the `record` elements.

Comment: I tried with above referenced statement thread @RMPR , but this again formatting my first line not the entire file. is there anyway we could use xpath to find a tag and its body to parse it with etree?

Comment: Since your document root is the tag `Message`, you can use a dedicated parser by extending the stlib class `HTMLParser` as highlighted on the answer linked or iterating over all the lines of the file to achieve what you want. Lmk if you still need a formal answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues:

1. There is no root in your doc. This can be solved by wrapping the xml text with `<root>..</root>`
2. The tag `remittance-details` is not closed so its is INVALID XML.

Comment: Hi, Yes we don't have root but all the xml starts and ends with <Message> and </Message>. However, for the remittance tag closure (Invalid XML) I, didn't share the complete xml as its huge (mentioned the same in my initial post)